# Select distinct gives incorrect values even if performed on primary key Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, distinct, cql, datastax, consistency

Im running Cassandra Version  2.1.2 and cqlsh 5.0.1

Here is the table weather.log, weather is the keyspace having consistency level One. 
I have 2 nodes configured.

`CREATE KEYSPACE weather WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-east': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;`

`CREATE TABLE weather.log (
    ip inet,
    ts timestamp,
    city text,
    country text,
    PRIMARY KEY (ip, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';`

When we run the query.

`select distinct ip from weather.log`

We get inconsistent, wrong responses. Once we get 99 just next time we get 1600 etc.  [where the actual number should be > 2000]

I have tried this query with consistency level set to ALL also. It dint work.

Why is this happening ? I need to get all the keys. How to get all the primary keys?

Comment: did you try adding ALLOW FILTERING clause?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT can only be used on a primary key.

Comment: @Raedwald ip is the primary key right?

Comment: @Whitefret no. I am not using ALLOW FILTERING cause ip is the primary key.

Comment: do you only do this request or do you write before your query?

Comment: This is the only query. It is not nested . stand alone simple query.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be effected by [CASSANDRA-8940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8940). I'd suggest to update to the latest 2.1.x release and verify if this issue is fixed for you.